# to show $A+B$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\max\{|x|,|y|\}\le 1\}$ and $B=\{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y\in\mathbb{R}\}$

We need to show $A+B=\{x+y:x\in A,y\in B\}$ is closed

I understand that $A$ is a compact (clearly closed and Bounded) subset and $B$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I know one result which I solved as an exercise from Principle of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin, that $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$ is compact and $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$ is closed  then $A+B=\{x+y:x\in A,y\in B\}$ is closed. If the above problem comes in an examination then should I prove the general result and draw the conclusion?

Could any one help me to solve the first problem how to conclude that $A+B$ is closed?

Comment: Note that for $a\in A+B$, $\lvert a_1\rvert \leq 1$, $a_2 \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could find out which theorems you are allowed to quote for this particular exam, but in this particular case, you do not need the power of a general theorem such as the one from Rudin, as it is very easy to see that the set $A+B$ consists of the points $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for which $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, and you can see (or prove) that this is closed very easily.

Comment: and $y$ can be anything right?

Comment: Yes, $y$ can be any real value (for a point in $A+B$).

Comment: may I know the name of  language or script of your display name?

Comment: The script is Cyrillic - used for writing Russian and some other languages.

Answer (score 3):

I give a valid proof in any normed space. Let $z_n=x_n+y_n\in A+B$ where $x_n\in A$ and $y_n\in B$ and $(z_n)$ is convergent to $z$. We'll prove that $z\in A+B$.

We have $x_n=z_n-y_n\in A$:compact set so there's a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ convergent to $x\in A$ since $A$ is closed. Hence $y_{n_k}=z_{n_k}-x_{n_k}$ is convergent to $y=z-x\in B$ because $B$ is also closed.

Finally we have
$$z=\lim z_n=\lim z_{n_k}=\lim x_{n_k}+y_{n_k}=x+y\in A+B,$$
So $A+B$ is closed.